# firewalld vs iptables

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw, firewalld

I have read on the internet that firwalld or ufw are the frontends of iptables, but I'm wondering why when start firewalld in my system iptables stop, and when I start iptables firewalld stop ?!

update [1]:

- what I mean by start and stop is that `systemctl status iptables` showing that its stop, not that it is not working properly.
- firewalld was not installed by default I  installed it

Comment: It might be that when you start firewalld your iptables rules get overwritten, and the same when you run your iptables script or restore or whatever, your firewalld iptables rules get overwritten. If you want/need more help, you will have to give us a lot more information.

Comment: @DougSmythies Thanks for the response, I edit it the post

Comment: ??? iptables is not a service. firewalld seems to be a service. I only use iptables myself.

Comment: I was going to log in and show you, however it seems I locked myself out from my server